# Time & option dependent data input (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vbscript

I ma trying to create a from that will allow users to enter data in to excel easy on a tablet.

[Start Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKtT.png)

[After Pressing Data Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImsMD.png)

As you can see data is being copied from txt field in to a specific cell (marked in yellow).

How do I format the query for this target cell to be dependent on current date (or picked data) and round picked from Start Form?

Form is to fill this spreadsheet below.

[Sample excel data spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zYF.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
Current Code for txt box:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim oRange As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
    Set sDate = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Set oRange = Nothing
    Set oRange = ws.Range("A:A").Find(sDate, xlValues)
    If Not (oRange Is Nothing) Then
        iRow = oRange.Row
        ws.Cells(iRow, iCol) = txtBox.Value
    End If


End Sub
```

But its compiling an error @ sDate Object Required yet dates including todays are in A:A row.

Code needs to look for todays date in AA column (green) then consider positions 1-8 (blue) - rounds from form and then input date in to green cells.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAHzZ.png)

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are asking. What is it that you want to do with the current time, the rounded time (from the starting form) and the PH measurement? Can you not just store the timestamp in an adjacent cell?

Comment: So each date has positions 1-8 which are rounds. I am looking for code that will identify todays date and depending on which round it is input data next to it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste in a screenshot or another image link show how you would like the output to look.

Comment: Code needs to look for todays date in AA column (green) then consider positions 1-8 (blue) - rounds from form and then input date in to green cells.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAHzZ.png

Comment: Looking at your code, don't use "set" for non-objects like the sDate string. Also rather store the date in a LONG as an Excel date serial number - which is probably what is being stored in column A anyway (make sure by trying to add 1 to any date cell in Excel - if its correctly recognised by Excel as a date, then adding 1 will add one more day to the result. If it throws an error, your dates are stored in a non-standard date format and Excel just treats it as text). Now use MATCH in VBA (https://excelchamps.com/vba/match/) to find the row index and add the radio button offset (1+8).